# Haskell Tic Tac Toe tuple board: How to generate possible moves?

Tags: haskell, tuples

So I have a Tic Tac Toe board, in the form of nested tuples, like so:

```
type Row = (Field, Field, Field)
type Board = (Row, Row, Row)

data Field = X | O | B
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Where B stands for empty. I need to take a player, a given board state, and then generate a list of all possible board states after the next move.

```
moves :: Player -> Board -> [Board]
```

However, I just can't figure it out. My initial thought is that I need to iterate through every field, to check whether or not it is empty, and then add a new Board to the list or do nothing. However, I see no way to iterate through all the fields. Even if I manually check every field with if statement or guards, how do I move onto the next field to check it, regardless of whether I end up with a possible move or not?

If I convert the board format into a list I could do it, but I feel like that defeats the purpose of this problem. There's got to be a better solution that doesn't require restructuring Board.

Comment: What's the definition of your `Field` type?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that one. I edited the post to include it.

Comment: Oh, just a suggestion -- you can define `Field` as simply `Maybe Player`, then use `Nothing` to represent an empty cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to iterate through the fields of a tuple -- tuples aren't intended for that. A list of lists is probably a more natural representation for this problem.

That said, you can implement this function with the board representation you're using by following the types. A move on a `Board` is a move on either the first, second, or third row. A move on a row is the placement of the player on either the first, second, or third field. The difficulty with your representation is that there's no simple way to map over a tuple, since tuples are generally heterogeneous. So instead, one thing you can do is write yourself a generic way to apply a function to a location in a tuple. Here's one way to do that (if the `Monad` stuff confuses you, mentally substitute "list of foo" everywhere you see `m foo` and you'll be okay):

```
mReplace1 :: Monad m => (a -> m d) -> (a,b,c) -> m (d,b,c)
mReplace1 f (a,b,c) = f a >>= \d -> return (d,b,c)

mReplace2 :: Monad m => (b -> m d) -> (a,b,c) -> m (a,d,c)
mReplace2 f (a,b,c) = f b >>= \d -> return (a,d,c)

mReplace3 :: Monad m => (c -> m d) -> (a,b,c) -> m (a,b,d)
mReplace3 f (a,b,c) = f c >>= \d -> return (a,b,d)
```

These functions provide a way to apply a function to the first, second, and third slots in a tuple, respectively. They're wrapped in a monad so that we can have a function that returns a list of possibilities for the slot, and automatically convert that to a list of possibilities for the tuple as a whole.

With these, we can write the overall function just by stringing these calls together.

```
moves p board = mReplace1 rowMoves board ++
                mReplace2 rowMoves board ++
                mReplace3 rowMoves board
    where rowMoves row = mReplace1 fieldMoves row ++
                         mReplace2 fieldMoves row ++
                         mReplace3 fieldMoves row
          fieldMoves B = [p]
          fieldMoves _ = []
```

That is: the moves for a board are all the possibilities for a move in row 1, plus all the possibilities for row 2, plust all the possibilities for row 3. For a given row, the possible moves are all the moves for slot 1, plus all the moves for slot 2, plus all the moves for slot 3. For a given slot, if there's already an X or an O there, then there are no possible moves; otherwise there's one possible move (placing the player in that slot).

Comment: Note that the `mReplace*` functions don't need a Monad -- just a Functor will do. For example, `mReplace3` can be rewritten as `fmap (\d -> return (a, b, d)) $ f c`.

Comment: Sorry, `fmap (\d -> (a, b, d)) $ f c`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that I've used before

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Piece    = O | X deriving (Eq,Ord)
type Position = (Int,Int)
type Board    = Map.Map Position Piece

positions = [(i,j) | i <- [0,1,2], j <- [0,1,2]]

spaces board = map (\pos -> Map.notMember pos board) positions

moves player board = map (\pos -> Map.insert pos player board) (spaces board)
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me, but this requires restructuring my Board type, which is something I'd specifically like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have stated, tuples is not a very good idea for this approach, since there is no way to traverse them.

You said you needed tuples, so there you go, I'm almost sure it works, test it.

### First your code how I would've done it

```
import Control.Monad (msum)
import Control.Applicative ((<*>), pure)

data Player = P1 | P2 deriving (Eq, Show)

data Field = X | O | B deriving (Eq, Show)

type Board = ((Field,Field,Field)
             ,(Field,Field,Field)
             ,(Field,Field,Field))

symbolToPlayer :: Field -> Player
symbolToPlayer X = P1
symbolToPlayer O = P2

checkThree :: (Field,Field,Field) -> Maybe Player
checkThree (a,b,c)
    | a == b && a == c = Just $ symbolToPlayer a
    | otherwise        = Nothing

winHorizontal :: Board -> Maybe Player
winHorizontal (r1, r2, r3) = msum $ map checkThree [r1, r2, r3]

winVertical :: Board -> Maybe Player
winVertical ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)) =
    msum $ map checkThree [(a,d,g), (b,e,h), (c,f,i)]

winDiagonal :: Board -> Maybe Player
winDiagonal ((a,_,c), (_,e,_), (g,_,i)) =
    msum $ map checkThree [(a,e,i), (c,e,g)]

hasWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player
hasWinner b = msum $ [winHorizontal, winVertical, winHorizontal] <*> pure b
```

---

### This is the part of nextStates function

```
boardBlanks :: Board -> Int
boardBlanks (r1,r2,r3) = rowBlanks r1 + rowBlanks r2 + rowBlanks r3

rowBlanks :: (Field, Field, Field) -> Int
rowBlanks (a,b,c) = foldr hack 0 [a,b,c]
    where hack B c = 1 + c
          hack _ c = c

changeBoard :: Field -> Int -> Board -> Board
changeBoard f i (a,b,c)
    | hack [a] > i    = (changeRow f (i - hack []) a, b, c)
    | hack [a,b] > i  = (a, changeRow f (i - hack [a]) b, c)
    | hack [a,b,c] > i= (a, b, changeRow f (i - hack [a,b]) c)
    where
        hack ls = sum $ map rowBlanks ls

changeRow f 0 row =
    case row of
         (B,a,b)   -> (f,a,b)
         (a,B,b)   -> (a,f,b)
         (a,b,B)   -> (a,b,f)
         otherwise -> row
changeRow f 1 row =
    case row of
        (B,B,a)   -> (B,f,a)
        (a,B,B)   -> (a,B,f)
        otherwise -> row
changeRow f 2 row =
    case row of
        (B,B,B)   -> (B,B,f)
        otherwise -> row

nextStates :: Board -> [Board]
nextStates b = os ++ xs
    where
        os = foldr (hack O) [] . zip [0..] $ replicate (boardBlanks b) b
        xs = foldr (hack X) [] . zip [0..] $ replicate (boardBlanks b) b
        hack f (i,a) ls = changeBoard f i a : ls
```